# When does the filtration in the limit of the Leray spectral sequence split?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, etale-cohomology, galois-representations, spectral-sequences

Let $\ell$ be a prime, and $k$ a field of characteristic $\ne \ell$. Let $f \colon X \to Y$ be a proper map of smooth projective $k$-varieties. The Leray spectral sequence says
$$
E_{2}^{pq} = H^{p}(\bar{Y},R^{q}f_{*}\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) \ \Longrightarrow\  H^{p+q}(\bar{X}, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) .
$$
In particular this means that there is a filtration on $H^{n}(\bar{X},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$ such that $E_{\infty}^{pq}$ (with $p+q = n$) are the graded pieces.

> **Question:** Are there conditions on $f$, $X$, and/or $Y$ that make this filtration split?

(This means that $H^{n}(\bar{X},\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) \cong \bigoplus_{p+q=n} E_{\infty}^{pq}$; even if the direct sum decomposition is not canonical.)

Let me point out explicitly that I am looking for a decomposition that is Galois equivariant.

Comment: In the complex case, the Leray spectral sequence degenerates at $E_2$ when the family $f \colon X \to Y$ is proper and smooth (i.e., *all* fibres are smooth). This was proven by Deligne. Maybe does his proof also work somehow in your context?

Comment: @FrancescoPolizzi — Thanks for your comment. What exactly do you mean with “degenerates”? (It usually only means the filtration, not the splitting.) Anyway, do you have a reference for Deligne's proof?

Comment: It means that all the differentials are zero at the $E_2$ level, so you have your (non-canonical) decomposition.
A reference is the paper by De Cataldo and Migliorini *The Decomposition Theorem, perverse sheaves and the topology of algebraic maps*, see in particular Theorem 1.5 (Deligne's papers are quoted just above it).  
https://www.google.it/search?q=degeneration+of+Leray+spectral+sequence&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a&gws_rd=cr&ei=7e_wUqC0AaHy4QSDnoHAAQ#

Comment: I suppose you are actually looking at $H^*(\bar{X},\mathbb{Q}_l)$, with $\bar{X}=X\times _k\bar{k}$ -- otherwise you have no Galois action.

Comment: @abx — You're absolutely right. I'll edit it in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Credits to Francesco Polizzi for putting me on the right track, by pointing to Deligne's work.

The important references for this are

- Deligne's thesis [“Théorème de Lefschetz et critères de dégénérescence de suites spectrales”](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number3.pdf) Publications Mathématiques de l'IHÉS. 35 (1968) pp. 107–126.
- Deligne's paper [“Décompositions dans la catégorie dérivée”](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/68_Decompositionsdans.pdf) in: Motives. Proceedings of Symposia in Pure Mathematics. 55 t1 (AMS 1994) pp. 115–128.

> I guess if one invokes perverse sheaves there might be more general answers. If anyone would like to give such a more general answer, I would be very grateful!

**[Edit]** As Dan points out below, working with perverse sheaves indeed helps: then there is a decomposition if $f$ is proper. **[/Edit]**

What follows requires that $f$ is smooth (and proper, which was already an assumption in the question). Here goes my attempt:

## The decomposition

In Deligne's thesis [“Théorème de Lefschetz et critères de dégénérescence de suites spectrales”](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/Number3.pdf) we find the following results:

- Proposition 2.1 states that in the derived category $D^{\textrm{b}}(\bar{Y})$ we have an isomorphism
  $$ \textrm{R}f_{*} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell} \cong \bigoplus_{i} \textrm{R}^{i}f_{*} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}[-i]. $$
  The proposition applies, since $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$ satisfies the *Lefschetz condition* by the relative hard Lefschetz theorem (this uses that $f$ is smooth and proper).
- Proposition 2.16 with $Z = \textrm{Spec}(k)$, can be applied (since $Y$ is smooth over $k$; and by the previous point). This gives
  $$ \textrm{R}(\Gamma f)_{*} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell} \cong \bigoplus_{k} \textrm{R}\Gamma_{*} (\textrm{R}f_{*}^{k} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}[-k]). $$

Taking the $n$-th homology group, then gives
$$ \textrm{H}^{n}(\bar{X}, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) = \bigoplus_{q} \textrm{H}^{n}(\bar{Y}, \textrm{R}f_{*}^{q} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}[-q]) = \bigoplus_{q} \textrm{H}^{n-q}(\bar{Y}, \textrm{R}f_{*}^{q} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}). $$
This last expression can of course be written in the usual way:
$$ \textrm{H}^{n}(\bar{X}, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}) = \bigoplus_{p+q=n} \textrm{H}^{p}(\bar{Y}, \textrm{R}f_{*}^{q} \mathbb{Q}_{\ell}). $$

## The Galois equivariance

If I am not mistaken, the above decomposition is Galois equivariant. I hope some expert can point out errors if I go astray. Here it goes:

- Deligne starts with a very general Proposition (1.2) where he works with the bounded derived category $D^{\textrm{b}}(A)$ of some abelian category $A$. In particular we can work with the category $D^{\textrm{b}}(Y \times_{k} \bar{k})$ of lisse $\mathbb{Q}_{\ell}$-sheaves *together with the Galois action*. Here one has to identify $\sigma^{*}\mathcal{F}$ with $\mathcal{F}$, just as when one defines the Galois action on $\ell$-adic cohomology (or when proving the functoriality of $\textrm{H}_{\textrm{ét}}^{i}(\_, \mathbb{Q}_{\ell})$).
- The next Theorem we need is (1.5), and this is Galois equivariant because the hard Lefschetz theorem is Galois equivariant. (Here I bluf that this also holds for the *relative* hard Lefschetz theorem.)
- Consequently the decomposition of Proposition 2.1 is Galois equivariant.
- And finally, therefore the decomposition of Proposition 2.16 is also Galois equivariant.

Comment: Hi Johan, I agree with you that the decomposition is Galois equivariant. You are also right that there is a more general version of your answer using the decomposition theorem. The point is that there is a funny "perverse" t-structure on $D^b(\overline Y)$ for which $Rf_\ast \mathbf Q_\ell \cong \oplus_i H^i(Rf_\ast\mathbf Q_\ell)[-i]$ holds for *arbitrary* proper morphisms $f$, here $H^i(-)$ means cohomology sheaves with respect to this perverse t-structure. This is one way of formulating the decomposition theorem. If $X$ didn't happen to be smooth we should replace $\mathbf Q_\ell$ ...

Comment: with the intersection complex $IC_X$. In any case the decomposition theorem does not imply that the filtration for the ordinary Leray spectral sequence splits in this generality, only for the *perverse* Leray spectral sequence. What you can say is that if all the perverse sheaves $H^i(Rf_\ast \mathbf Q_\ell)$ occuring in the decomposition happen to be actual sheaves (as opposed to complexes of sheaves), then the Leray spectral sequence degenerates and the filtration splits.

Comment: (Here's some self-promotion: in Section 2 of my preprint http://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7369 is an example of proving Leray degeneration for a specific proper but not smooth morphism by precisely this method: checking that the perverse sheaves in the derived pushforward are actual sheaves.)

Comment: @DanPetersen — Thanks for the extensive comments! I guess I am going to study the perverse situation pretty soon. (But I do not know anything yet about t-structures, &c.) First I want a better understanding of the smooth projective situation. I will definitely look at your preprint. Thanks again!